# Python DynamoDB scan() filterExpression dateTime compare

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to construct a DynamoDB scan() that filters based on date. The date in the database is represented as a string. The code I currently have seems to work, but only if the input date and string in the database are formatted perfectly.

```
if len(filterExpression) > 0:
    filterExpression = filterExpression + ' AND '
filterExpression = filterExpression + '#dateAfter > :dateAfter'
expressionAttributeNames['#dateAfter'] = 'timestamp'
expressionAttributeValues[':dateAfter'] = dateAfter #string date

params = {
    'FilterExpression': filterExpression,
    'ExpressionAttributeNames': expressionAtributeNames,
    'ExpressionAttributeValues': expressionAtributeValues

}

data = table.scan(**params)
```

Is there a way to compare the 'timestamp' attribute as dateTime object? I know that dateutil works well for parsing dates from strings, but I am still unsure how to work the filterExpression to compare as dateTime objects rather than strings. Thank you for any help!

Comment: I was having issues with this too and ended up saving timestamps as epoch. Maybe not possible for you. Otherwise the filterexpression, according to the docs, happens after reading all the data. Is pandas or even excel a possibility to manage datatypes and post scan filtering?

Comment: Good note, appreciate the input! Yes, I could potentially filter post scan, but my understanding is that scan() is a rather inefficient/expensive action so it is best to try to minimize its activity. Query() performs much better but requires knowledge of the primary keys. For now, I think direct string compare is a best option for my project.

Comment: I think that’s what I’m saying about your methodology. You aren’t saving anything with filterexpression as scan() is executed and then the filtering. If you want reduced output query() is the method as you’ve noted.

Comment: Ahh I was not aware that scan() would be inefficient even with the filterexpression. That is good to know, thank you. So it would be easiest to just run table.scan() and then filter after.